# How to make a KPI appear next to a value in a column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to work my way around, adding **KPIs** next to a desired value.

I have tried this so far by using this in the calculated column formula field

```
<img src=" "/_Layouts/images/kpidefault-" & If ([Product cost] - [Materials cost] > 0
```

Basically i want to say a **Green KPI** should appear if the difference is > 0.

Any help appreciated. 
Many thanks.

Comment: "<img src=" "/_Layouts/images/kpidefault-" & If ([Product cost] - [Materials cost] > 0" this is what I tried

Comment: formula is incomplete

Comment: explain what exctly your poutput is expected, url img src seems to incomplete

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula:

```
=IF([Product cost] - [Materials cost]>0,[Product cost] - [Materials cost]&"<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/splashyIcons/arrow_large_up.png'>","")
```

(since your icon URL is invalid, I changed it to the URL of an icon on the internet)

Don't forget to set the data type of the calculated column to *Number*, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Formula won't save because there is an extra **(** To output HTML Datatype can be anything but Text. ``Number`` will add an extra DIV and align the HTML to the Right. Other datatypes have different alignment

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that extra bracket. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

`=If ([Product cost] - [Materials cost] > 0,[Product cost] - [Materials cost],"")`

This formula will give you the difference of `[Product cost]`, `[Materials cost]` if it is greater than zero, else it will be blank.

To combine what you want, try this formula.

```
   = '<img src="/_Layouts/images/kpidefault-"' & If ([Product cost] - [Materials cost] > 0,[Product cost] - [Materials cost],"") & '/>'
```

PS: Source is used as is from question. Make sure your image source is valid.

Comment: This Formula will never save because there are no outer quotes

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for displaying an Image with a Calculated Column (in a View only) is:

```
="<img src='image.gif'>"
```

(you need to set the Datatype to output as anything **but** Text, different datatype will output different Alignments)

There are 3 default images available by SharePoint

[image]

as

```
="<img src='/_layouts/images/kpidefault-0.gif'>"
="<img src='/_layouts/images/kpidefault-1.gif'>"
="<img src='/_layouts/images/kpidefault-2.gif'>"
```

You want the green image to be displayed based on a calculation: *this is pseudo code*:

```
IF( [Product cost]-[Materials cost] > 0 , GREEN , NOTHING )
```

So the full Calculated Column Formula is:

```
=IF([Product cost]-[Materials cost]>0,"<img src='/_layouts/images/kpidefault-0.gif'>","")
```

To add the difference as label:

```
=[Product cost]-[Materials cost] & 
 IF( [Product cost]-[Materials cost]>0 
     , "<img src='/_layouts/images/kpidefault-0.gif'>"
     , ""
   )
```

- It is perfectly valid to add linebreaks and spaces, SharePoint will ignore them **when you paste the Formula in the Calculated Column and save it**.
  If you always start from a texteditor (Notepad) like this, you have more insight in the flow of your Formula.
- Excel can be helpfull in building Formulas, as most basic Functions are the same  See

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

- It is a PITA to debug Calculated Columns. Because you don't get feedback until you save a Formula (with an undescriptive message) and you end up having to click multiple times to get back to your Formula. I have written a small 'CalcMaster' bookmarklet which hooks into the formula-editor and does a save of the Formula on every keypress; giving immediate feedback.  See: https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster

#### created from a 0, 1 ... Number value

If you want to create an image based on a Number field,

The Formula is (*pseudo code*):

```
="<img src='/_layouts/images/kpidefault-" & NUMBER & ".gif'>"
```

#### CSR

With (SP2013+) Client Side Rendering, all this can be simplified with some minor JavaScript code and  the OpenSource [iCSR.Github.io](http://iCSR.Github.io) Library

```
        iCSR.Me({
            Fields: {
              "Priority":{
                View : iCSR.Priority
       }});
```

Produces **an interactive View**:

[image]

#### Update #1 HTML only

Here is HTML code to color the profit as text using CSS

```
="<span style='"
 & IF( [Product cost]-[Materials cost]>0 
     , "color:green;font-weight:bold"
     , IF( [Product cost]-[Materials cost]<0 
           , "color:red"
           , "color:black"
         )
   )
 & "'>"
 & [Product cost]-[Materials cost]
 & "</span>"
```

Comment: How can I choose your answer as the best answer. Thanks alot. It solves my query. Very good tutorial